# How to change the precision of a large matrix to a certain value efficiently

Tags: matrix, memory, precision-and-accuracy

I want to change the precision of a $3\times8400\times3072\times2$ matrix to 25, it's original precision is 5. Here is my code:

```
matrix = SetPrecision[Import["matrix.dat"], 25]];
```

However, I find it can not work because the RAM of my computer (12 GB) is not enough even though I set the virtual memory of my computer to 120 GB. So is there any good method to make it with the limited RAM？

Comment: `it's original precision is 5` can you please explain what does this mean? Do you mean you used `SetPrecision` on the numbers already?

Comment: @Nasser, By "it's original precision is 5" I mean the format of the data in file "matrix.dat" is "%.5f".

Comment: But then if the number itself only contains this many  decimals in it, what then do you mean by you want to change its precision to 25?  Where will the extra precision come from? This is what is not clear to me by what you are doing.

Comment: I will use $Findfit$ function to fit this matrix, then there is a warning " the precision of the data is less than WorkingPrecision (20)". So I want to change precision of the original data.

Comment: The array really is too big to work in extended precision. A reasonable estimate is 5G, and that does not account for intermediate space that might be used e.g. if internals copy all or part of it. Even if the RAM suffices, once linear algebra operations are performed the usage will grow by some factor (three at least I would expect, since matrix factorizations generally produce a new matrix and also use another of same size for intermediate storage). Best bet is to reduce dimensionality of the problem or live with the warning andfind a good way to validate the result.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau. I choose to live with the warning now. :)